# Multiple dex files error with signpost and gdata jars

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

My app requires both `signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar` and one of Google's libraries `gdata-core-1.0.jar`. But the signpost jar has some of the classes packaged in the gdata-core package. So,  my app project is not building. Here is the error:

```
 Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gdata/util/common/base/Escaper;
```

How can I fix this conflict.. I need both the jars for different purposes within my app.

Comment: You may need to repackage one of them. See https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still keep two jars, but you would need to modify / repackage one of them to resolve runtime conflicts

- You need to decide what jar you will use for that conflicting class
- Open one of jars with 7zip (or alternative) and remove the path\to\Conflict.class file
- save the new jar
- update classpath to include new jar in your IDE