# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gdata/util/common/base/Escaper

Tags: android

I'm using "core-1.47.1.jar" and "signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar" in my project. Both the jar file has "Escaper" class with same package hierarchy, that's why I'm getting the above error, plz see the image below [image]

I tried solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645436/multiple-dex-files-error-with-signpost-and-gdata-jars) but when I removes/rename package in one of conflicting jar, it flags this error "***Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536***". Please help.